# Problems with setCookie

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout, setcookie

I Believe I'm doing this correctly but it is not getting the stored cookie information

login.php

```
session_start(); 
      $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
      $_SESSION['password'] = $pass;
          if(isset($_POST['remmemberme'])) 
    { ob_start();
        setcookie("kitbusername", $_SESSION['username'], time()+60*60*24*100); 
        setcookie("kitbpassword", $_SESSION['password'], time()+60*60*24*100); 
        echo '<script>
      window.top.location.href = "index.php";
      </script>';
    }
```

index.php

```
 <p class="welcome">Hello 
        <?php 
session_start();
 if($_COOKIE['kitbusername']){echo $_SESSION['username'];} 
                 elseif($_SESSION['username']){
                         echo $_COOKIE['kitbusername'];
                 } else{
                   echo 'Guest';
                                  }?>
</p>
```

header.php

```
<?php session_start(); 
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) || isset($_COOKIE['kitbusername'])){
//Log Out Button// ?>
```

session start is set on all pages

Comment: is that the correct format for setcookie()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use `session_start()` on index.php

After calling `ob_start()` do you call [`ob_end_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php), [`ob_end_flush()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php), [`ob_clean()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php), or [`ob_flush()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)?

Comment: If you don't know what they mean you probably don't mean to be using `ob_start()`. But those are the functions you call *after* calling `ob_start()` all of which control output buffering. You probably don't need to be doing that in your script.